# Doom - setting code formatter for specific file type

Tags: doom, formatting, web-mode, ide

How can I change formatter used for specific file type in doom-emacs `format` module?
So far I've been happy with using mostly doom defaults and haven't gotten into writing custom configurations and seriously using Elisp, so I'm a bit lost.

I'm trying to use doom-emacs as an IDE for Laravel development and I'm running into problems with Blade files. The main one being wrong code auto formatting. Prettier run from the command line has no problem formating the files, but doom defaults do. Eg.:

Input:

```
@section('content')
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
          <article class="article">
     </article>
       @endforeach
@endsection
```

Result:

```
@section('content')
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<article class="article">
</article>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

Expected:

```
@section('content')
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <article class="article">
        </article>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

I'm using `+onsave` option. The files are opened in `web-mode` and the extension is `*.blade.php`. And I think it's using lsp formatting by default.

I've tried using `(set-formatter! 'prettier  "prettier" :modes '(web-mode))` and setting `format-with-lsp` to `nil` just to see if I can force the web-mode itself to use prettier. But no luck.

1. How can I change the formatter used?
2. How can I specify on which file extension it should be used?

I've been searching [format-all](https://github.com/lassik/emacs-format-all-the-code), [Doom](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs), Googleing and trying find something in the source code, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The package behind the `format` module is `format-all`. Going down the rabbit hole, its method of determining the current buffer's language is delegated to [language-id](https://github.com/lassik/emacs-language-id), which has a nice DSL for detecting web-mode peculiarities. Adding a entry for blade may cut it:

```lisp
(after! format-all
  (add-to-list 'language-id--definitions
               '("PHP"
                 php-mode
                 (web-mode
                  (web-mode-engine "blade")))))
```

Or, you could use `web-mode-buffer-indent` :)

Comment: `web-mode-buffer-indent` does the same thing :/
I've tried the code you provided, but it seems that the `'language-id--definitions` variable is not defined in Doom.

Comment: What do you mean by "does the same thing"? What happens when you use it? Also, try wrapping the snippet with `(after! format-all ...)`, maybe the reason it's not defined for you is related to doom's lazy module loading

Comment: 1. Using `web-mode-buffer-indent` function formats the code in the same way.
2. That just break doom and prevents it from starting (almost) at all.
It seems you get a theme loaded and some modules in the background, but other than that just a blank screen and read-only buffer. It looks like the var is not defined anywhere, if you do `describe-variable` in `web-mode` and look for it it's nowhere to be found :(

Comment: My bad, the language-id thingy was added after the `format-all` version pinned by Doom. Try adding `(unpin! format-all)` to your `packages.el` file

Comment: Still no dice. `Error in private config: config.el, (void-variable language-id--definitions)`.
Just to be sure the code (`(after! ...`) should be in `config.el`, right?! I'm just not sure what else can be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Doom has now switched from using `format-all` to the [`apheleia`](https://github.com/radian-software/apheleia) package to handle formatting, and `prettier` is already the default formatter for `web-mode` buffers, so for the purposes of this question it is only necessary to ensure that `web-mode` is enabled for `*.blade.php` files, see: [how do I enable web-mode .blade.php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35047815/2948807) for details in how to do that in case it is not already configured in Doom (which I think it is).